# TFS commits unchanged files

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, tfs

I'm using both TFS 2008 and 2010, and I thought that when you check in a file that is unchanged, TFS should automatically determine that there were no changes, and undo the change instead of creating a new changeset for it.

To test this, I am simply checking out any single file in my solution (e.g. web.config). I then (without making any changes) check it back in immediately. I view the history of the file and see there's a new changeset for it. When I compare that file to the previous version, it says "The files are identical".

I thought it wasn't supposed to create a new changeset since the file wasn't changed. I thought this is the way it is supposed to work, and I also thought this is the way it used to work for me. Am I mistaken? Does anyone have an ideas on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have determined what was causing my issue. My organization recently enabled the Local Security Policy setting "System cryptography: Use FIPS compliant algorithms for encryption, hashing, and signing" on all computers. Apparently, VS/TFS 2008 and 2010 don't exactly handle this setting too well, and the check in/comparison of files was one place where it caused a conflict.

By design, VS 2008 and VS 2010 should only commit files that have indeed changed. If a file is pending but has not been actually modified, it should undo the checkout when you tell it to check the file in. But, when the FIPS setting is enabled, it seems to commit the file no matter what.

To resolve the issue, you need to disable the FIPS setting and also restart Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

It will if you are using local workspaces but not for server workspaces. Local workspaces were introduced in TFS 2012 with VS 2012 and are not comparable with previous versions.

I have note used 2010 let alone 2008 in a few years, however if I remember correctly you are explicitly saying that you want to check out the entire solution and then check in. In a server workspce, to improve performance on potentially large codebases it does not do those checks.